# Firefox first tab weird language

Tags: firefox, language-support

When launching Firefox through Terminal with:

```
firefox
```

I get this output:

```
(process:10923): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
1427987784903   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonsByTypes: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:533:34) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonsByTypes@GMPProvider.jsm:533:35 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonsByTypes_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2132:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonsByTypes_concatAddons@AddonManager.jsm:2137:11 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonsByTypes@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:389:5 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonsByTypes_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2132:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonsByTypes_concatAddons@AddonManager.jsm:2137:11 < getAddonsByTypes_getVisibleAddons@XPIProvider.jsm:3829:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < asyncMap_gotValue@XPIProviderUtils.js:180:7 < asyncMap_callback@XPIProviderUtils.js:187:9 < completeAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:134:5 < getAddon@AddonRepository.jsm:580:7 < this.AddonRepository.getCachedAddonByID</<@AddonRepository.jsm:586:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
1427987785014   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonByID: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:518:8) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonByID@GMPProvider.jsm:518:9 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonByID@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:362:7 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < getAddonByID_getVisibleAddonForID@XPIProvider.jsm:3815:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < getRepositoryAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:126:5 < this.XPIDatabase.getAddon/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:1069:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
1427987785018   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonByID: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:518:8) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonByID@GMPProvider.jsm:518:9 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonByID@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:362:7 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < getAddonByID_getVisibleAddonForID@XPIProvider.jsm:3815:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < getRepositoryAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:126:5 < this.XPIDatabase.getAddon/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:1069:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
1427987785022   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonByID: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:518:8) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonByID@GMPProvider.jsm:518:9 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonByID@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:362:7 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < getAddonByID_getVisibleAddonForID@XPIProvider.jsm:3815:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < getRepositoryAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:126:5 < this.XPIDatabase.getAddon/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:1069:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
1427987785027   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonByID: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:518:8) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonByID@GMPProvider.jsm:518:9 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonByID@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:362:7 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < getAddonByID_getVisibleAddonForID@XPIProvider.jsm:3815:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < getRepositoryAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:126:5 < this.XPIDatabase.getAddon/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:1069:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
1427987785031   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider GMPProvider.getAddonByID: TypeError: this._plugins is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm:518:8) JS Stack trace: GMPProvider.getAddonByID@GMPProvider.jsm:518:9 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < LightweightThemeManager_getAddonByID@LightweightThemeManager.jsm:362:7 < callProviderAsync@AddonManager.jsm:235:12 < getAddonByID_nextObject@AddonManager.jsm:2012:1 < AOC_callNext@AddonManager.jsm:311:7 < getAddonByID_safeCall@AddonManager.jsm:2017:13 < getAddonByID_getVisibleAddonForID@XPIProvider.jsm:3815:7 < makeSafe/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:145:17 < getRepositoryAddon@XPIProviderUtils.js:126:5 < this.XPIDatabase.getAddon/<@XPIProviderUtils.js:1069:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:870:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:749:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:691:37 < XPI_showUpgradeUI@XPIProvider.jsm:2348:5 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2118:13 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
```

And this is the first tab that it launches:

[image: Firefox funny language]

My language settings seem fine, and I do not remember installing this language on my system so it beats me why my first tab on Firefox is in that language. So that is really my question, why do I get this strange language as my startup page and what do these error messages mean?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 37.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Candidate: 37.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 37.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: According to Google and Wikipedia that's Turkish. Have you Turkish language support installed?

Comment: @UTF-8: Nope, never installed that.

Comment: And I just checked my language settings and that is not an installed language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally end up at a multi language web page when starting Firefox, and the language used depends on the browser's language preference settings. Go to  **Edit -> Preferences -> Content** and click the **Choose...** button to change it.